# VPN connection with Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, vpn

Is there a way to establish a VPN connection programmatically in Objectiv-C for the iPhone? Are there somewhere good tutorials for this?
Does anyone know?

Thanks alot

Comment: iphone only for paid VPN ip address and login password , so u can free for ip address then not connection succes bcz iOS update policy not access third party free ip address , if  free vpn ip damage device .. it possible  only recommended paid ip address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think third-party applications have access to those APIs.

Comment: Thnks St3fan , I read ur reply on more or less the same question here at stackoverflow but i asked this again as i have found this app link using VPN. itunes.apple.com/us/app/pocketphilanthropist/id349076629?mt=8#. 

Its quite annoying sometimes when you have no authentic sources to confirm if particular tasks can be done using iPhone Available (Public) APIs. Whats the preferred way of finding it out?. Shall we go through iPhone documentation every time or mail Apple ( by the way they offer only 2 technical calls/yr :) , what do u suggest

Comment: @TaimurAjmal: Please check this: http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/