# if possible start VPN connection in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

as topic, I want establish VPN connection in iPhone app, if it possible? but seem not public API for this purpose ...

anyone give tip, thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to establish a connection programmatically? Theoretically you could roll an IPsec client on your own, but that's not a trivial task on any platform. Edit: I also notice that there is support for SSL VPN, which might be easier to implement than IPsec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen RDP over VPN using the iPhone (though I haven't set it up myself) and [Cisco indicates support](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/iPhone/2.0/connectivity/guide/iphone.html) for VPN connections from iPhone on their ASA series:

And [Apple provides instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1424).

So VPN connections using a variety of protocols are definitely possible. However, initiating the connection programmatically is a different matter.

I did some additional reading (including old posts here on SO like [VPN connection with Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678408/vpn-connection-with-objective-c)).

The more that I think about it, allowing an application to quietly initiate a VPN connection could pose a big security risk. I would be surprised to see API support for it.

However, creating your own VPN client on the iPhone (though MUCH more difficult than making an API call) is still theoretically possible.